# What should be the type of ref variable for Ant Design Tree component?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types, antd, react-typescript

What should be the correct type for the treeRef variable here in TypeScript?

```
const SomeTree: FunctionComponent = () => {
  const treeRef = useRef();

  return (
    <Tree
      showLine
      treeData={treeData}
      ref={treeRef}
    />
  );
};
```

I get this when I hover over the error but can't figure out the correct type to give.

[Typescript VS Code Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BYqkf.png)

Comment: You can use `GetRef` provided by antd to get the type of ref of Tree component. `import { type GetRef, Tree } from 'antd';` 
`const treeRef = useRef() as MutableRefObject<GetRef<typeof Tree>>;`

Comment: Thanks @MuhammadNoumanRafique. I used the same approach and this worked. This is my version for the same - `type TreeRef = GetRef<typeof Tree<DataNode>>;
  const treeRef = useRef<TreeRef>(null);`